# Sharing information between releases in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an ADO release pipeline, which has multiple releases.

I want to share information between releases. Basically the new release needs to know the details about the last release. Is there a way to do that?

I was thinking of using artifacts to share this information, but looks like "Publish Pipeline Artifacts" is not supported for the release pipeline : https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8812

What is a good way to achieve this capability?

Comment: What information are you trying to share? Each release should be independent of prior releases; wanting to share state across them is weird. How does your proposal handle a case of no prior releases? How about a re-release of the same build? What about skipped environments?

Comment: Can you provide detailed example of what do you want to share between releases? what kind of information?

Answer (score 0):

To let the new release know the details about the last release. You can add a powershell task in your release pipeline to call azure devops [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

You can use below restful api get the the release information.

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=5.1
```

Below is an example in powershell script.

```
$lastRelease =$(Release.ReleaseId) -1 

$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/release/releases/$($lastRelease)?api-version=5.1"

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method get

echo  $result
```

[image]

**Note:**
To run above script in your release pipeline powershell task, You need to go to **Agent Job** and make sure **allow scripts access to the OAthen** token is checked

[image]
[image]